# Conditional where clause based on another parameter

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have 3 tables :

```
Stores (
    store_Id
)

Products(
    product_Id,
    store_Id
)

Price(
    product_Id,
    currency,
    price   
)
```

My problem statement is like this:

Produce a result set such that:

if store_Id is 1, then select those Products which have prices less
 than 3

if store_Id is 2, then select those Products which have prices less
 than 5

if store_Id is 3, then select those Products which have prices less
 than 6.5

Result set should contain columns: store_Id, product_Id, currency, price.

I am able to do this in Java by running a query like this in loop and substituting the parameters and finally collecting all the result:

```
select ... 
from stores s join products p on s.store_Id = p.store_Id
join price pr on pr.product_Id = p.product_Id
where s.store_Id = ?
and pr.price <= ?
```

**My question is**: can this be achieved in SQL itself in just 1 query without using java (reason is: Products and Prices is a mammoth table containing many thousands of records)

I'm on DB2 v10.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can incorporate this logic into the `WHERE` clause:

```
select ... 
from stores s
inner join products p
    on s.store_Id = p.store_Id
inner join price pr
    on pr.product_Id = p.product_Id
where
    (s.store_Id = 1 and pr.price < 3) or
    (s.store_Id = 2 and pr.price < 5) or
    (s.store_Id = 3 and pr.price < 6.5);
```